# CURL returns full string response instead of xml

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to pull data using CURL in PHP like this

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('Content-type: text/xml',"openapikey:da21d9s56ekr33");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.test.co.un/rest/cateservice/category");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); 
$return = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($return);
print_r(gettype($return)); //prints string
```

but i got the response in full string when the response supposed to be in xml format, and when i print the type of the response variable it prints string. I tried using Postman to check the response and it returns the correct format in XML mode:

[image: xml format]

and when i change to Preview mode in Postman, it showed the same result as what my CURL response in php shows, which is full string:

[image: string format]

Comment: I haven't found it necessary to specify headers when retrieving XML with curl, try without the headers. I simply use: $curl = curl_init("URL"); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);; $result = curl_exec($curl)

Comment: @mayersdesign i need to put the header for authentication using api token

Comment: not directly related with your question but use https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle it is easier faster and most probably will solve all your problems.

Comment: browse your browser response as a source and see

Comment: @hassan when i inspect the element it shows the xml tag inside the html body, how can i retrieve it?

Comment: this is because you are printing your response, by hitting CTRL+U in firefox for example you will show your response source .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

most likely, you're getting the correct response, its just your browser not rendering it the way you expected it to. what happens if, at the top of your code, you add `header("content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8");` ? my guess, it will render the code the way you expected it to.  alternatively, html encode it, like

```
function hhb_tohtml(string $str):string
{
    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
}
print_r(hhb_tohtml($return));
print_r(gettype($return)); //prints string
```